# Test with postman or django-rest-framework test

Tags: django-rest-framework, automated-tests, postman-testcase

i have a doubt about the tests in drf, did you use the [test drf](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/)  or postman?
or maybe you do both because in postman you create the documentation and and you can do a constant monitoring, what thing do you recommend  me?

Answer (score 0):

Use postman or other tool to check how your api is working and then make the tests. Tests are always good as if you change a code related to certain test you can immediately perform the test and check how it behaves.